Repeat value of column X for each ID

rep <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,4), c(164, 157, 302, 505))
colnames(rep) <-c("SchoolID", "Distance")

stud <-data.frame(c("Jay","Karen","Jorge","Jonas","Leo","Pedro","Carol","Julia","Adam","Kobe","Shaq"),c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,5))
colnames(stud) <- c("Student Name","SchoolID")

Now I want "Distance" to repeat to every student based on their School - Every student that goes to "School 1"  has distance "164" and so on

stud$distance = rep$Distance[match(stud$SchoolID, rep$SchoolID)] You might want to search for [r] match() on SO or look into the help file (help("match")).

While you can indeed use match, I would just do a join. Either merge(stud, rep), or perhaps dplyr::left_join(stud, rep, join_by(SchoolID)).
